# parse xml data using php

Tags: php, xml

Dear all ,I have the sample files below.I can parse data from the simple xml tag.But how can i parse data from this type of xml tag?< p:price >test data< /p:price> or < p1:translation lang="en" type="text" >pls guide..

sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <mynotes>
   <note>
     <tasks>Task 1</tasks>
     <details>Detail 1</details>
   </note>
   <note>
     <tasks>Task2</tasks>
     <details> Detail 2</details>   
   </note>
      <test>test data</test>
    </mynotes>
```

php code...

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$objDOM->load("abc.xml"); //make sure path is correct
$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("note");  
foreach( $note as $value )
  {
    $tasks = $value->getElementsByTagName("tasks");
    $task  = $tasks->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $details = $value->getElementsByTagName("details");
    $detail  = $details->item(0)->nodeValue;    
    echo "$task :: $detail<br>";
  }

  $test = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("test");
  $testValue  = $test->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo $testValue;
```

i cannot parse data from  < p1:translation lang="en" type="text" > this type of tag..pls guide me how can i parse data from this type of tag or < category:applicationCategory > this type of xml tag....

thanks
riad

Answer (score 1):

You need to query by namespace as well as tagname. There is the getElementsByTagnameNS method for that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php

Comment: sorry ..i don't get u..i have a tag like this...< p:price >100 dollar < /p:price>..how i can retrieve the info between this tag..pls guide..on your provided example just showing the separated tag name like p and price..but i need the between info...

Comment: That <prefix:name> syntax is shorthand for writing <my-namespace:name>, so you would query by the namespace that is bound to the p or p1 prefix. E.g. if p is declared like this: xmlns:p="test" it means that to query for p:price is equivalent to query for price elements in the "test" namespace. So in that case you'd supply the "test" namespace.

In other words: ignore the "p" prefix, use its namespace directly.